# Finding the answer to integral $F = \int_{a'}^{b'} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^\frac{1}{2}dx$

Tags: integration

Can you help me with the idea for solving the following integral?

\begin{equation}
F = \int_a^b \left( \dfrac{x-\varepsilon_1}{x-\varepsilon_2} \right)^\frac{1}{2} \,dx
\end{equation}
or, put in another form,

\begin{equation}
F = \int_{a'}^{b'} \left( 1+ \dfrac{1}{x} \right)^\frac{1}{2} \,dx
\end{equation}

Comment: **Hint:** Let $t=\dfrac1x$ and $u=\sqrt{1+t}.$

Comment: I couldn't figure out how this substitution solves the integral.
Could you give me another hint?!
@Lucian

Comment: @MaziarNoei: try $x=\sinh^2 u$.

Comment: @MaziarNoei: The two substitutions reduce the integrand to a rational function.